# Apache with SSL crash using WAMP Server

Tags: apache, ssl, wampserver

I was able to install the SSL cert on my wamp 2.2 and was able to run it for 5 minutes. But after few refresh, the https site will not load. I need to restart the wamp services again to make it run.

Am I missing something?

I'm running wamp 2.2 on windows 2008 server with a godaddy certificate.
My site is currently running on 80 and 443. When my https site crashes my http site is still working normally.

I cannot see any significant error log on my apache error log:

> [Sat Mar 28 04:05:13.070114 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2576:tid 380] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Sat Mar 28 04:05:13.070114 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2576:tid 380] AH00456: Server built: May 13 2012 19:54:49
>
> [Sat Mar 28 04:05:13.070114 2015] [core:notice] [pid 2576:tid 380] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2'
>
> [Sat Mar 28 04:05:13.070114 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2576:tid 380] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4528
>
> [Sat Mar 28 04:05:13.926979 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4528:tid 276] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

UPDATE:

Messages from ssl-access log

> x.x.x.x - - [31/Mar/2015:15:17:51 +0800] "GET /js/bootstrap-affix.js   HTTP/1.1" 200 3205
>
> x.x.x.x - - [31/Mar/2015:15:17:51 +0800] "GET /img/xbook_686x400_preloader.swf HTTP/1.1" 200 362032
>
> x.x.x.x - - [31/Mar/2015:15:17:52 +0800] "GET /img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150
>
> x.x.x.x - - [01/Apr/2015:19:06:41 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12406
>
> x.x.x.x. - - [01/Apr/2015:19:15:23 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12406

Comment: When you setup SSL(443) you normally create another set of log file for example `\wamp\logs\ssl_access.log` and `\wamp\logs\ssl_error.log` Have you looked at those log files for any clues??

Comment: I dont see any error on my ssl_error while on ssl_access this is what i have.

Comment: xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/Mar/2015:15:17:51 +0800] "GET /js/bootstrap-affix.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3205
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/Mar/2015:15:17:51 +0800] "GET /img/xbook_686x400_preloader.swf HTTP/1.1" 200 362032
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/Mar/2015:15:17:52 +0800] "GET /img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150
x.x.x.x - - [01/Apr/2015:19:06:41 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12406
x.x.x.x. - - [01/Apr/2015:19:15:23 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12406